# Java how do I convert a byte[] containing multiple doubles into a double[]

Tags: java, arrays, casting, signal-processing, fft

I have a sound file that I am practicing phase vocoding on. I have converted the bytes of the file into a double[] and manipulated the wave form of that file through a Fast Fourier Transform and inverse Fast Fourier Transform. The issue is now I need to convert the byte[] back into a double. Here are some useful code fragments:

How I converted the data in the first place:

```
/**
 * Converts bytes from a TargetDataLine into a double[] allowing the information to be read.
 * NOTE: One byte is lost in the conversion so don't expect the arrays to be the same length!
 * @param bufferData The buffer read in from the target Data Line
 * @return the double[] that the buffer has been converted into.
 */
   private static double[] bytesToDoubleArray(byte[] bufferData){
    final int bytesRecorded = bufferData.length;
    final int bytesPerSample = getAudioFormat().getSampleSizeInBits()/8; 
    final double amplification = 100.0; // choose a number as you like
    double[] micBufferData = new double[bytesRecorded - bytesPerSample + 1];
    for (int index = 0, floatIndex = 0; index < bytesRecorded - bytesPerSample + 1; index += bytesPerSample, floatIndex++) {
        double sample = 0;
        for (int b = 0; b < bytesPerSample; b++) {
            int v = bufferData[index + b];
            if (b < bytesPerSample - 1 || bytesPerSample == 1) {
                v &= 0xFF;
            }
            sample += v << (b * 8);
        }
        double sample32 = amplification * (sample / 32768.0);
        micBufferData[floatIndex] = sample32;

    }
    return micBufferData;
}
```

and what I am doing to the data:

```
public static byte[] shift(byte[] data, int factor){
    double[] audioData = bytesToDoubleArray(data);
    audioData = Arrays.copyOf(audioData, roundToPowerOf2(audioData.length));
    Complex[] transformed = FFT.fft(doubleToComplex(audioData));
    transformed = shiftArray(transformed, 3);
    Complex[] reverted = FFT.ifft(transformed);
    for(int i = 0; i<reverted.length; i++){
        audioData[i] = reverted[i].re();
    }
    return null;//How do I convert audioData[] back into a byte[]????
}
```

Any ideas on how to remedy this problem? Any solutions would be greatly appreciated. Also any Java libraries that already implement phase vocoding would be awesome as well.

Comment: Look into `ByteBuffer`.

Comment: You can do it by reading the spec for Double.

Comment: But you're not converting bytes <=> double, you're effectively converting bytes <=> integer and converting the integer to double.  And if you convert the double result back to bytes using the same scheme you will lose some significance.

Comment: "Losing some significance" may be perfectly acceptable depending on the application.

Comment: Bug me later tonight and I'll write up a (reasonably) correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is, approximately.  I'm sure I've screwed something up.  scaleFactor would presumably be 327.68, to reverse the scaling above.  The above code appears to be big endian.  Whether you want fullNormalize is up to you.

```
public byte[] doubleArrayToByteArray(double[] input, int bytesPerSample, double scaleFactor, boolean fullNormalize, boolean bigEndian) {
    byte[] result = new byte[input.length * bytesPerSample];
    performNormalization(input, scaleFactor, fullNormalize);
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        long sourceVal = (long)(input[i] * scaleFactor);
        sourceVal = sourceVal >> 8 * (8 - bytesPerSample);
        for (int j = 0; j < bytesPerSample; j++) {
            int index = i * bytesPerSample;
            if (bigEndian) {
                index += (bytesPerSample - j);
            }
            else {
                index += j;
            }
            result[index] = (byte) sourceVal;
            sourceVal = sourceVal >> 8;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

public void performNormalization(double[] input, double scaleFactor, boolean fullNormalize) {
    double maxVal = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        double val = Math.abs(input[i]) * scaleFactor;
        if (val > maxVal) {
            maxVal = val;
        }
    }
    if (fullNormalize || maxVal > Long.MAX_VALUE) {
        double normalizeFactor = (double)(Long.MAX_VALUE) / maxVal;
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            input[i] *= normalizeFactor;
        }
    }
}
```

**Updated:** Realized that I needed to account for scaleFactor in normalization.  And you'd not normally specify both a `scaleFactor` that was not 1.0 and `fullNormalize = true`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by converting double[] to byte[]. Recall that typically double is 8 bytes length while byte is 1 byte long.

If you can convert your double somehow to an unsigned integer 0-255 (or signed -128 - 127) then you just need to cast each double to byte and assigned it to a new array, otherwise you have to use ByteBuffer:

```
int capacity = // calculate how much space you need for your byte array
ByteBuffer byteBuf = ByteBuffer(capacity);
for(double d : doubleArray) byteBuf.putDouble(d);
byte[] byteArray = byteBuf.array();
```

Effectively the above method did not convert anything but you're just interpreting the byte stream as a sequence of bytes rather than sequence of double

Comment: If you read the original code, N bytes of integer (where N is variable) are converted into one double value, and presumably one would want to convert the doubles back into N integer bytes each.  It's not simply mapping doubles into a byte buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Just as you did when you converted from `byte[]` to `double[]`, you will now need to convert back to `byte[]`. Just create a new `byte[]` array and manually copy the data from the `double[]` array:

```
private static byte[] doublesToByteArray(double[] a) {
    int len = a.length;
    byte[] b = new byte[len];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        b[i] = (byte) a[i];
    return b;
}
```

This of course assumes that the data in the `double[]` array can be stored in a `byte[]` array without further conversion / scaling. Otherwise you will need to take care of that when copying.

Comment: Not going to work very well for cases where there's 3-4 bytes of significance, is it?

Comment: That is why I mention that further conversion / scaling may or may not be necessary depending on the application. It is not my task to question the OP's motives -- I am just answering the actual question.